# How to avoid - This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable?

Tags: android, realm

What is the best practice for using the Realm instance? In my code everywhere where I am using the realm instance, after I am done with the realm instance I  close it there itself, yet I often run into this issue.

For example,

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
     realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
     realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
         if(realmUser != null) {
               // do some realm database related operation here
         }
     });
    } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close(); // close immediately after use
            }
        }
```

In, my case here is where this error occurs:-

```
static void setUserEmailVerifiedToRealm(){
         User realmUser = getUserFromRealm();

         Realm realm = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {  // Exception
                if(realmUser != null) {
                    realmUser.setEmailVerified(true);
                    Log.d("xxx", "Email verified");
                }
            });
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static User getUserFromRealm(){
        Realm realm = null;
        final User[] user = new User[1];
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
                user[0] = realm1.where(User.class).findFirst();
            });
        } finally {
            if(realm != null) {
                realm.close();
            }
        }
        return user[0];
    }
```

I am not able to understand how to fix this issue, any pointer will be really appreciated.

Comment: A managed RealmResults/RealmObject can only be accessed if at least one local Realm instance is open on the given thread, see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle